# String replace issue

Tags: c++, string

I have the following code which is supposed to replace digits with "*", and letters with "?", but for some reason, it partially works. Could you help me figure out what is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    //Declaring Variables
    int MAX = 10;
    string niz = "";

    do {
        //Letting user insert a string
        cout<<"Write a random set of characters (max. "<<MAX<<" signs): ";
        getline(cin, niz);

        //Comparing the size of string with allowed maximum
        if (niz.size() > MAX){

            //Print error message
            cout<<"String too long."<<endl;
        }
    } while (niz.size() > MAX);

    //Iterating through the string, checking for numbers and letters
    for (int i = 0; i <= niz.size(); i++){

        //If the sign is a digit
        if (isdigit(niz[i])){

            //Replace digit with a "*"
            niz.replace(i, i, "*");

          //If the sign is a letter
        } else if (isalpha(niz[i])){

            //Replace vowel with "?"
            niz.replace(i, i, "?");
        }
    }

    //Printing new string
    cout<<"New string, after transformation, is: "<<niz<<", and its length is: "<<niz.length()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `i <= niz.size()` should be `i < niz.size()`.  What did you find when you stepped through your code with your debugger?

Comment: I actuall went with just less than, but it still yielded the same result, so I thought maybe it doesn't iterates through all the characters.

Comment: It helps if you tell us what input you are giving, what output you are getting and what output you are expecting.

Comment: Well, the below response fixed the problem.
But let's see why this doesn't work..
I input "1234567", and after transformation I get "*****" (only 5 stars), don't know where the last 2 stars dissapeared.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `i` in the line `niz.replace(i, i, "*");` should be a `1`. Your code will replace the 9th character with `*********` (9 *'s). If the substring is smaller tahn the 2nd argument, `replace` will copy the substring until as many characters as possible are replaced

If you are just replacing one char in a string use:

```
niz[i]='*';
```

Note the single quotes (') around the character.

Comment: Thanks, this works, didn't know I can directly replace the characters that way.

Comment: @BloodDrunk don't forget to upvote if the answer works for you

Answer (score 0):

You are using the 5<sup>th</sup> form of [`std::string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace):

```
 basic_string& replace( size_type pos, size_type count,
                        const CharT* cstr );
```

which is replacing `count` (=`i` here) characters from the position `pos` (also = `i` here).
Note that `"*"` with double quotes is a string, not a single character.

You just need to do

```
niz[i] = '*';
```

with single quotes.